Delay when using WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP with map
I used WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP in conjunction with map to handle key press events but it created lag when I pressed too many keys at the same time.
Below is the code I use to handle this event.
std::map<Key, KeyStatus> StatusKey;

void UpdateKeyEvent(const MSG& msg) noexcept
{
    switch (msg.message)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        SetStatusKey(msg.wParam);
        return;

    case WM_KEYUP:
        ReUpStatusKey(msg.wParam);
        return;
    }
}
void SetStatusKey(const WPARAM& wParam) noexcept
{
    Key key = static_cast<Key>(wParam);
    if (StatusKey.find(key) == StatusKey.end()) {
        StatusKey.insert(std::make_pair(key, Down));
        return;
    }
    else {
        if (StatusKey[key] == NONE_GET || StatusKey[key] == Up) {
            StatusKey[key] = Down;
        }
    }
}
void UpdateStatusKey() noexcept
{
    for (auto& Key : StatusKey)
    {
        if (Key.second == Down)
        {
            Key.second = Hold;
        }
    }
}
void ReUpStatusKey(const WPARAM& wParam) noexcept
{
    Key key = static_cast<Key>(wParam);
    StatusKey[key] = Up;
}
float GetKeyRaw(const Key& key) noexcept
{
    if (StatusKey.find(key) != StatusKey.end()) {
        if (StatusKey[key] != Up && StatusKey[key] != NONE_GET) {
            return 1.0f;
        }
    }
    return 0.0f;
}

and in a main loop, I use UpdateKeyEvent like this
while (TRUE)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        UpdateKeyEvent(Msg);
        if (Msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;
    }
}

In short, my current implementation of keyboard input handling using the Windows message loop probably has too many flaws. I'd like advice from everyone on how to optimize my input handling code. Thanks You!
PS :
I tried using GetKeyState, GetAsyncKeyState and GetKeyboardState but they all don't function exactly like the way I coded it above.

Why is GetKeyRaw returning a float instead of a bool?

Why is SetStatusKey taking a const reference to a WPARAM?  WPARAM is just an integer. It doesn't need to be passed by reference.

@selbie I return it as a float because I have a separate function to return a bool value and
I use const references because I'm quite used to it.

I'm guessing there's more code in the while(TRUE) loop. It is a common mistake to have a costly operation following every message that was handled producing noticeable lag. The solution is to handle all messages currently queued and then do the costly operation before starting over.

Idea #1
Your SetStatusKey is making three lookups it seems.  Once with the find call and then two additional lookups with the StatusKey[key] == comparisons.
Change this:
void SetStatusKey(const WPARAM& wParam) noexcept
{
    Key key = static_cast<Key>(wParam);
    if (StatusKey.find(key) == StatusKey.end()) {
        StatusKey.insert(std::make_pair(key, Down));
        return;
    }
    else {
        if (StatusKey[key] == NONE_GET || StatusKey[key] == Up) {
            StatusKey[key] = Down;
        }
    }
}

To this:
void SetStatusKey(const WPARAM& wParam) noexcept
{
    Key key = static_cast<Key>(wParam);
    auto itor = StatusKey.find(key);
    KeyStatus status = itor == StatusKey.end() ? NONE_GET : itor->second;
    if (status == NONE_GET || status == Up)
    {
        StatusKey[key] = Down;
    }
    
}

Idea #2
Stop using std::map and use std::unordered_map instead.  O(lg N) vs O(1) performance tradeoff.
Idea #3
Just use an array.
KeyStatus StatusKey[256] = {};

And somewhere in your code, you'd initialize the the array to all Up or NONE_GET values values before your main loop starts. Then you don't need to use .find() or any other method. You can just access the array directly like this:
BYTE keyIndex = (BYTE)wParam;
StatusKey status = StatusKey[keyIndex];
if (status == NONE_GET || status == Up)
{
    StatusKey[key] = Down;
}

Idea #4.  Similar to #3, but don't use WM_KEYDOWN or WM_KEYUP messages to keep the key state updated. Just poll the entire keyboard state using the GetKeyboardState function on each iteration of your game loop. When I worked in a game studio a long time ago, this is what we used to poll the keyboard on each frame.

In your first example, you are still performing 2 lookups if the key already exists in the map. You can instead modify the second value of the iterator you already have: void SetStatusKey(const WPARAM& wParam) noexcept { Key key = static_cast<Key>(wParam); auto itor = StatusKey.find(key); if (itor == StatusKey.end()) { StatusKey.insert(std::make_pair(key, Down)); } else if (itor->second == NONE_GET || itor->second == Up) { itor->second = Down; } } }

@RemyLebeau - That's a great suggestion.
